# Как в android изменить цвет поля?

Tags: android, цвета

[image: Фото поля]

1. Как называется это поле?
2. Как изменить его цвет в приложении?

Comment: Статусная строка или статусбар.

Comment: Глянь тут http://fire-monkey.ru/topic/1954-android-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%86%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%81-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC/

Comment: тему установите для приложения

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Изменить стиль можно таким способом:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    Window window = getWindow();
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
    window.setStatusBarColor(Color.BLUE);
}
```

либо создаем стиль:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```